# How to call external API with parameters from the Twilio function

Tags: axios, twilio, twilio-functions, twilio-autopilot

I am trying to write one Twilio function. Inside the Twilio function, I have one external API call with parameters for one of my API. API will return the result and that result I am passing using "Say" tag.

I have one Twilio Autopilot Bot in which I have one task added. On execution of that task it will call "Action URL" which is the Twilio function URL.

But somehow this full flow is not working. I think my external API call using AXIOS is not proper. Can you help me to call external API with parameters from the Twilio function? For my Twilio function check following code

Thanks in advance

```js
exports.handler = function(context, event, callback) {
    const responseData = await axios.post(`API_PATH/GetMessageData`,'Minute':'3000','MessageType':'2,3'});
    const resultData = responseData.data;    
    let response = {};
    response.actions = [];
    response.actions.push({"say":"hello sam" + resultData})
    callback(null,response)
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are calling `axios` using `await`, but you have not declared the function to be an `async` function.

You should also ensure to catch any potential API or connectivity errors when making external requests. That will also show if there's an error in calling your API.

```js
exports.handler = async function(context, event, callback) {
    try {
        const responseData = await axios.post(`API_PATH/GetMessageData`,'Minute':'3000','MessageType':'2,3'});
        const resultData = responseData.data;    
        let response = {};
        response.actions = [];
        response.actions.push({"say":"hello sam" + resultData})
        callback(null,response)
    } catch(error) {
        console.error(error)
        let response = {};
        response.actions = [];
        response.actions.push({"say":"There was a problem with the bot, please try again."});
        callback(null, response);
    }
};
```

**Edit**

You also added that your result looks like this:

```json
{
  "Message": {
    "Text": "Data retrieved successfully"
  },
  "MessageList": [
    { "ContactNo": "+91xxxxxxxx", "Message": "test message", },
    { "ContactNo": "+91xxxxxxxx", "Message": "test message 2", }
  ]
}
```

I'm not sure exactly which of those messages are what you want to send back to the user. Perhaps you want to send both of the `Message`s inside the `MessageList` object? You could do that like so (just showing the part of the code inside the `try`):

```js
        const responseData = await axios.post(`API_PATH/GetMessageData`,'Minute':'3000','MessageType':'2,3'});
        const resultData = responseData.data;    
        let response = {};
        response.actions = [];
        resultData.MessageList.forEach((message) => {
            response.actions.push({"say": message.Message });
        }
        callback(null,response)
```

This loops through the `MessageList` and adds a new `say` action to the response with each message.

Comment: thanks its working.

I need one more help. My result json is 

{
    "Message": {
        "Text": "Data retrieved successfully",
    },
    "MessageList": [
        {
            "ContactNo": "+91xxxxxxxx",
            "Message": "test message",
        },
        {
            "ContactNo": "+91xxxxxxxx",
            "Message": "test message 2",
        }
    ]
}

how to fetch MessageList value in the above function?

Comment: Not exactly sure what you want the result to be there, but I've edited my answer with a suggestion.